# LINQ grouping with aggregate

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate, grouping

I am trying to create query that retrieves emails and users and I'd like to use the aggregate function to have all users with the same email in one field.
My query gives me an error on **new** keyword as Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'AnonymousType#2'

Here is the code.

```
var Users = from usr in
            (from au in _lldat.aspnet_Users
                     join am in _lldat.aspnet_Membership on au.UserId equals am.UserId
                     select new  { au.UserName, am.LoweredEmail })
            group usr by new { usr.LoweredEmail } into grp 
            select new {
                           uEMail = grp.Key,
                           uName = grp.Aggregate((a, b) => new { LoweredEmail = a.LoweredEmail, UserName = (a.UserName + ", " + b.UserName + ", ") }).UserName 
                       };
```

I do not see what i am doing wrong. Any help will be graitly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to remove it and it did not help. The error stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch the parameters in the *new* keyword.
It would be like this:

```
var Users = from usr in
            (from au in _lldat.aspnet_Users
                     join am in _lldat.aspnet_Membership on au.UserId equals am.UserId
                     select new  { au.UserName, am.LoweredEmail })
            group usr by new { usr.LoweredEmail } into grp 
            select new {
                           uEMail = grp.Key,
                           uName = grp.Aggregate((a, b) => new {UserName = (a.UserName + ", " + b.UserName + ", "), LoweredEmail = a.LoweredEmail }).UserName 
                       };
```